# Allocating Balance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have come across a problem at work where I have run out of ideas. I do not write PL/SQL but I am familiar with it somewhat from school classes.

Here is the table structure I have:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HateThis](
[CustID] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
[Company_Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Total_Balance_Available_For_Allocation] [INT] NOT NULL,
[TotBAL] [INT] NOT NULL,
[Due_0] [INT] NOT NULL,
[Due_1_10] [INT] NOT NULL,
[Due_11_30] [INT] NOT NULL,
[Due_31_60] [INT] NOT NULL,
[Due_61_90] [INT] NOT NULL,
[Due_91_120] [INT] NOT NULL,
[Due_121_150] [INT] NOT NULL,
[Due_151_180] [INT] NOT NULL,
[Due_180+] [INT] NOT NULL,)
```

`INSERT INTO HateThis VALUES (6106,'Google','1000','500','150','100','50','0','0','0','0','0','0');
INSERT INTO HateThis VALUES (6107,'Google','1000','500','150','150','0','0','0','0','0','0','0');
INSERT INTO HateThis VALUES (510,'Yahoo','500','10','10','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0');
INSERT INTO HateThis VALUES (511,'Yahoo','500','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0');
INSERT INTO HateThis VALUES (512,'Yahoo','500','40','5','15','15','4','1','0','0','0','0');
INSERT INTO HateThis VALUES (513,'Yahoo','500','500','500','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0');
INSERT INTO HateThis VALUES (514,'Yahoo','500','1200','1000','200','0','0','0','0','0','0','0');
INSERT INTO HateThis VALUES (106,'Alta Vista','0','50','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','42');
INSERT INTO HateThis VALUES (107,'Alta Vista','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0');
INSERT INTO HateThis VALUES (109,'Alta Vista','0','11','11','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0');`

Columns info:

- **Total_Balance_Available_For_Allocation** = How much total money this company  has that can be allocated to accounts under it.
- **TOTBAL** = Total due for that account (due_0+due_11-10+d11-30...)

I am to write a query such that it assigns balance from **Total_Balance_Available_For_Allocation** to the account with the oldest due balance (It looks at **Due_180+** first if there is any due balance and it is less than what is available then that amount is allocated under this column, if there is zero balance it looks into **Due_151-180** and continues until **Due_0**.

If there still money left in **Total_Balance_Available_For_Allocation** then look at the next account for the same company and see if it can be allocated to any of the columns in that account.

This problem is hard to explain. Please let me know if I can explain it better.

This is what I have done so far:

```
  when total_balance_to_allocate > abs(total_balance_available) and  totbal <=  abs(total_balance_available) and totbal = a2_currbal then 'post into a2_currnal'
  when total_balance_to_allocate > abs(total_balance_available) and  totbal <=  abs(total_balance_available) and totbal = D0_10 then 'post into D0_10'
  when total_balance_to_allocate > abs(total_balance_available) and  totbal <=  abs(total_balance_available) and totbal = D11_30 then 'post into D11_30'
  when total_balance_to_allocate > abs(total_balance_available) and  totbal <=  abs(total_balance_available) and totbal = D31_60 then 'post into D31_60'
  when total_balance_to_allocate > abs(total_balance_available) and  totbal <=  abs(total_balance_available) and totbal = D61_90 then 'post into D61_90'
  when total_balance_to_allocate > abs(total_balance_available) and  totbal <=  abs(total_balance_available) and totbal = D91_120 then 'post into D91_120'
  when total_balance_to_allocate > abs(total_balance_available) and  totbal <=  abs(total_balance_available) and totbal = D121_150 then 'post into D121_150'
  when total_balance_to_allocate > abs(total_balance_available) and  totbal <=  abs(total_balance_available) and totbal = D151_180 then 'post into D151_180'
  when total_balance_to_allocate > abs(total_balance_available) and  totbal <=  abs(total_balance_available) and totbal = D180PLUS then 'post into D180PLUS'
```

Desired output to be like:

CustID   ,   Company_Name  ,   Do_This

6106     ,   Google        ,   Post 300 to due balance

6107     ,   Google        ,   Post 200 to due balance

106      ,   Alta Vista    ,   Insufficient money

108      ,   Alta Vista    ,   Insufficient money

512      ,   Yahoo         ,   Post 40 to due balance

514      ,   Yahoo         ,   Post 460

510      ,   Yahoo         ,   Insufficient money

513      ,   Yahoo         ,   Insufficient money

Comment: please check this link(https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to know more on how to improve question

Comment: I don't think you can use PL/SQL with Sql-Server, so one of your tags must be wrong.

Comment: @TabAlleman Oh I did not know that! :(

Comment: A better explanation would be for you to show what the expected output should be, and post the sample data as text instead of an image.

Comment: @TheGameiswar Thanks for the link. To be honest, it way too long  to read so I just focused on what I missed. :)

Comment: I think its worth the effort,try going through the link,it saves your time and others time as well

Comment: @scsimon I do not know how to paste sample data as text. There are so many column as you can see, it was all messy when I tried to paste from SQL Server.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, Syed? If I understand correctly, the balance in total_available_for_this_account needs to be applied, starting with D180PLUS, working your way back toward D0_10, until you run out of funds in total_available_for_this_account. Do you need the result set to be a list with a row for each company, and a dollar amount to allocate to each of the aging buckets (D columns)?

Comment: Syed if you had bothered to actually read that article is explains how to format data so it will post nicely. Since reading an article about how to make your post easier for others is TLDR (too long didn't read), I find your question TSDH (too sloppy didn't help).

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry I did not mean to come off with a tldr attitude. It is just that this table has so many columns to write INSERT INTO statement for. So, I thought it would be best to paste it into excel and take a screenshot. All I honestly wanted to do was to save time :( I did include what I have done so far after reading that article.

Comment: Here is the real issue Syed. There are several people here trying to help. The challenge is that you need help writing the sql. Many of the good folks in here are more than capable of writing the sql. But we also are very meticulous and want to test our sql before posting it because posting sql that doesn't work goes against the concept of helping. But we don't have any tables to work with so we either have to create them manually from a screen shot, hope our code works, or don't bother putting in any effort. We don't get paid to help so making it easier for us benefits you.

Comment: @Syed Zaidi - use this tool to build your tables in and send us all the link when you are complete. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @DanielG Yes, I am using SQL Server. The balance in total_available_for_this_account needs to be applied, starting with D180PLUS, working your way back toward D0_10, until you run out of funds in **total_balance_available**. I need the result set to be a list with a row for each company, and a dollar amount to allocate to each of the aging buckets.

Comment: @SeanLange OK, I will create a table. Did not know taking a screenshot was a bad idea :(  Sorry, my fault.

Comment: @Isaiah3015 Will use that tool. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanLange I included create table script. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Isaiah3015 I included create table script. I hope it helps.

Comment: Man you are making this so much harder than it needs to be. I get that you are frustrated because you are struggling but this is the time you really need to focus on the details. Your sample output doesn't match the sample data. You have CustID values that are not in the sample data. And there is no explanation about the calculations here. Why are some "post to due balance" and others are "post"? How do you expect anybody to be able to decipher this?

Comment: @SeanLange :(  I will improve my question. You are right about the lack of details in my desired output. Thank you for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample output doesn't match your actual table. Looking at your post, you have rules to determine on the column "do_this" but did not explain how you determine those values. As well as the explanation to determine to allocate the oldest balance.

I think you have more rules to add than this but I hope this helps you point the right direction.

```
   Select
   a.[CustID]`enter code here`
  ,a.[Company_Name]
  ,a.[Total_Balance_Available_For_Allocation]
  ,a.[TotBAL]
  ,b.TotalDue
  ,case when a.Total_balance_available_for_allocation >b.TotalDue Then 
             a.Total_balance_available_for_allocation-b.TotalDue 
        else ''
        End AllocationAmountBalance

   ,case when a.Total_balance_available_for_allocation < b.TotalDue then 
   'Insufficient Money'
        else ' '
        end BalStatus

   from .[dbo].[HateThis] a
   JOIN (select ([Due_0]+[Due_1_10]+[Due_11_30]+[Due_31_60]+[Due_61_90]+
            [Due_91_120]+[Due_121_150]+[Due_151_180]+[Due_180+]) as TotalDue
            ,[CustID]

     From [dbo].[HateThis] ) b on a.custid = b.custid
    order by a.[Company_Name], a.custid`enter code here`
```